# Auth0: Custom claims not added to access_token

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

I was trying to add user email to access token, but when I log in using getTokenSilently from auth0-spa-js I don’t get any custom claim.
I added it using auth0 rules system that I know works for me because I used it also for email whitelist which works.

I also tried to add it in the idToken copying some examples but none of them worked for me.

This is the rule I used:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    const namespace = 'https://myapiserver.me';
    context.accessToken[namespace+'email'] = user.email;

  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

This is the decoded access token that I got

```
{
“https://acme.com/claims/role”: “admin”,
“iss”: “https://-----.eu.auth0.com/”,
“sub”: “google-oauth2|--------------”,
“aud”: [
“https://myapiserver.me”,
“https://----.eu.auth0.com/userinfo”
],
“iat”: -------,
“exp”: -------,
“azp”: “------”,
“scope”: “openid profile email”,
“permissions”: [
“add:task”,
“get:task”,
“sync:task”
]
}
```

And There isn't any custom claims in there

(I have removed all of my infos using -)

Comment: Can you try using a different property.. Name it as customeremailaddress making sure that it is not present in existing claim registry.  These would be helpful in your scenario. https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current/sample-use-cases#add-custom-claims-to-a-token
https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml#claims
https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/jwt-claims#custom-claims
https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/claims-namespacing